# Product manifold volume element

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M=N_1 \times N_2$ be a 4-dimensional Riemannian product manifold with metric $g_M=g_{N_1} + g_{N_2}$, where $g_{N_1}=g_{ij}du^i du^j$ (with $i, j= 1, 2$) and $g_{N_2}=g_{ab}dv^a dv^b$ (with $a, b= 1, 2$) are metrics of $N_1$ and $N_2$, respectively.

Is correct write the volume element as usual, i.e., $vol(M)= \int{du^1 du^2 dv^1 dv^2}\sqrt{det(g_M)}$ ?

Comment: If $(u^1,u^2)$ is a coordinate system of $N_1$ and $(v^1,v^2)$ of $N_2$, then $(u^1,u^2,v^1,v^2)$ is a coordinate system of $M$.Your formula is then correct.

Comment: @Didier - Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: I should add that your formula is locally correct, that is the volume element is given by the integrand. But of vourse, there may not be a global coordinate patch, unless $N_1$ and $N_2$ both have such a patch.

Comment: @Didier - Thank you very much also for the precious clarification